# Getting properties of a new tab in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-addons

I want to create a Chrome add-on that collects information about a new tab that is opened in Chrome. I would like to know why just using .onCreated.addListener callback function does not return the newly created tab, or if it does, why I can't access any of the properties(the way I do in my second attempt with chrome.tabs.query).

I guess I'm confused with regards to what is returned by:

**chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener's callback function**
//In developer notes it's described as: 'returns details about the new tab'
//http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated
**vs.**
**chrome.tabs.query callback function**
//My understanding that it returns an array of Tab objects

```
//Assumed one Tab object is returned
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(theTab){
    for (var x = 0; x < theTab.length; x++){
         alert(theTab[x].title);
    }
});

//Active Tab object is returned
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(theTab){
        var url = theTab[0].url; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreated`'s callback returns a `Tab` object for the newly created tab, while query (as specified) should return all active tabs as an array. You shouldn't be trying to loop through a non-existent array.